# Compile Dojo Classes with Google Closure Compiler ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS

Tags: javascript, dojo, google-closure-compiler

I am new to Google Closure Compiler. I want to obfuscate my Dojo classes and modules. I have an HTML page that initiates VehicleCreator class (Acts as Layer). This class includes all the Vehicle Classes A, B, C,...... These vehicle classes calls some  functions from Helper modules and classes while as helper modules and classes also call each other functions.

**HTML**

**VehicleCreator**

- **Vehicles**

  - A
  - B
  - C
  - D
  - .
  - .
  - .
- **Helper**

  - Module A
  - Module B
  - Helper Class A
  - Helper Class B

I have created classes using define like:

```
define(["....."],  function (....) {
        var A = declare([Evented], { declaredClass: "A",
         Name :"A Type"
         constructor: function (param1, param2) {   },
         init: function (param1, param2) {  },
         create: function ([params]) { },
         throwEvent: function (p, q) { /*Throws event back to calling HTML */},
        //**    Other internal Functions and Function that also use functions from Module A and Helper Class A
        });
        return A;
    });
```

and modules like this:

```
define(["...."], 
  function(...){
    return {
         getTyres:  function(type) {
          return tyres;
        },


    };
});
```

In each class **create(), throwEvent()** and **init()** are the functions that are common to all classes and called outside class. I have read https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/limitations When I compile single class it renames functions and I am unable to use them.

**Q #1:** How to compile classes while not renaming these function names or should I point compiler to index HTML file so that it sniffs these functions and leaves them intact?

**Q#2:** Is there any way to compile and obfuscate all classes in a folder?

**Q#3:** How to obfuscate and concatenate them in a single file for better loading performance?

Sorry for multiple questions in a single post but these all are related.

Comment: did you read https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/build/ ?

Comment: I am using loader configuration and layer class. Can you please elaborate what specifically you are referring to? Do you mean to say that by obfuscating all classes would be compiled into a single file?

Comment: Dojo build system uses google closure, can discover the class to compile based on a build profile, and concatenate everything into one or more files (based on the profile). So all the questions are solved if you use the native dojo build system

Comment: Thanks for the hint

Comment: BTW I use dojo that is already minified along with other custom libraries in it. Moreover Dojo itself do not use ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS as I can see in their release version code. Function names are not mangled as it is   done by Google Compiler.